# How create just small square check-box in JQM, inside a table?

Tags: jquery-mobile

This code:

```
<td>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
    </label>
</td>
```

yields this: [image: wide], which is wide. I want only the check-box square part, like the check-boxes [in this demo](http://www.stokkers.mobi/jqm/tableview/demo.html). Writing only `<td><input type="checkbox"></td>` creates simple check-box (not JQM style), since it's inside a table.

Does somebody has simple solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you will not be able to customize the by default developed HTML control. what I meant is just taking out the square portion from check box.

The link you share is doing it with the help of css classes and images.

Initially.

```
<label class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-checkbox-on 
ui-btn-up-c" data-theme="c" for="selectRow-2">
<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all" aria-hidden="true">
<span class="ui-btn-text">
</span>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-checkbox-on">
</span>
</span>
</label>
```

Later on when you click the square with help of java-script they have just swapped classes.

```
<label class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-checkbox-off ui-btn-up-d" 
data-theme="d" for="selectRow-1">
<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all" aria-hidden="true">
<span class="ui-btn-text">
</span>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-checkbox-off">
</span>
</span>
</label>
```

The easiest way would be using some thing similar in your layout and swapping the classes with JS.

Comment: Yes, this is the regular HTML-CSS-JS method. Are you sure there is no out-of-box JQM method to do it ?

Comment: nope there isn't. I'm doing the same and am re-formatting the checkbox CSS, so that only the box is visible. I posted a feature request on JQM, but I guess it's far down the wishlist :-)

Comment: @frequent, where's the link to add `+1` for this feature ?

Comment: @Tal: it's been movet to the [feature request page](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/Feature-Requests), issue was [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3246).